Assigning band name when using QgsRasterFileWriter/QgsRasterDataProvider in PyQGIS
I want to write binary data to a new raster file using PyQGIS QgsRasterFileWriter. Everything works fine but I would like to also assign a specific band name to the written raster band. How can I do this?
writer = QgsRasterFileWriter(raster_file_path)
writer.setOutputProviderKey("gdal")
writer.setOutputFormat(QgsRasterFileWriter.driverForExtension("tif"))

provider = writer.createOneBandRaster(Qgis.DataType.Float64, cols, rows, extent, crs)
block = QgsRasterBlock(Qgis.DataType.Float64, cols, rows)
block.setData(data)
provider.writeBlock(block, band=1)

I found no relevant methods or parameters on the documentation pages of the objects:

QgsRasterFileWriter
QgsRasterDataProvider
QgsRasterBlock


Maybe the writer.setCreateOptions() method ? It accepts a string list (QStringList) of options.

That allows to set https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/gtiff.html#creation-options but I am not aware of any way to set these tiff tags that way.
